# Cannot find a header with 'include_directories' in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, include

Here is the folder hierarchy of a c++ project:

```
 1. FolderA
    1. file1.h/cpp
    2. CMakeLists.txt (CmakeA)
 2. FolderB
    1. file2.h/cpp
    2. CMakeLists.txt (CmakeB)
 3. main.cpp
 4. CMakeLists.txt (CmakeAll)
```

CmakeA:

```
file(GLOB FolderA_FILES *.cpp *.h *.hpp)

# add component
add_library(FolderA ${FolderA_FILES})

include_directories(../FolderB)
target_link_libraries(FolderA FolderB)
```

CMakeB:

```
file(GLOB FolderB_FILES *.cpp *.h *.hpp)

# add component
add_library(FolderB ${FolderB_FILES})
```

CMakeAll:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

#add smirk dependency
set(Smirk_DIR /usr/local CACHE PATH "Directory where Smirk has been installed (e.g. /usr/local).")
include(${Smirk_DIR}/cmake/smirk.cmake)
smirk_project(operatingTableProject)
file(GLOB smirk_operatingTableProject_FILES *.cpp *.h *.hpp)
add_executable(smirk_operatingTableProject ${smirk_operatingTableProject_FILES})

# install directives
install(
    TARGETS smirk_operatingTableProject
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)

#add FolderB dependency
add_subdirectory(FolderB)
target_link_libraries(smirk_operatingTableProject FolderB)

#add FolderA dependency
add_subdirectory(FolderA)
target_link_libraries(smirk_operatingTableProject FolderA)
```

In the `file1.h` I include `file2.h`. The problem is wherever I include in the `main.cpp` `FolderA/file1.h` I got a compilation issue:

```
file2.h: No such file or directory (in file1.h)
```

But if I comment out the include in the `main.cpp`, it works. Also, If I include `file2.h` in `file1.cpp` it works so the main problem is wherever I include a header file from a subdirectory in another header file from other subdirectory and one of them is included in the main file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: with double-quotes ""

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Command `include_directories` affects only on *local* scope: being issued in `FolderA` it affects **only** on the compilation of `FolderA` library. You need to issue that command in top-level `CMakeLists.txt` for compile `main.cpp`.

Alternatively, you may use command [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) with *PUBLIC* option in `FolderA`:

```
target_include_directories(FolderA PUBLIC ../FolderB)
```

so include directories will be propagated to any target which is linked with that library.