# Skeleton project for CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use CMake for the first time for a project and need some help setting up a project the way I like it. I'm probably doing everything wrong, so please bear with me. I currently have the following directory structure:

```
/CMakeLists.txt
/main/CMakeLists.txt
      main.cc
/libfoo/CMakeLists.txt
        libfoo.h
        libfoo.cc
```

Here `libfoo` is a git submodule that should be includable in other projects as well. My CMakeLists.txt files are as follows:

/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)
project(server)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
add_subdirectory(main)
add_subdirectory(libfoo)
```

/main/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(MAIN_SRCS
    "main.cc"
) 
add_executable(server
    ${MAIN_SRCS}
)
target_link_libraries(server
    libfoo
)
```

/libfoo/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)
project(libfoo)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(LIBFOO_SRCS
    "libfoo.cc"
    "libfoo.h"
)
add_library(libfoo STATIC
    ${LIBFOO_SRCS}
)
```

My current `main.cc` is extremely simple:

```
#include "libfoo.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return 0;
}
```

However, this doesn't currently compile as the `libfoo.h` header isn't found. My questions are therefore:

1. Why isn't the `libfoo.h` header visible, since I've added the library as a target_link_library for the executable?
2. Is there a better way to set up the CMakeLists.txt files?
3. I would prefer to have the required include directory for the `libfoo.h` library to be of the form `#include "libfoo/libfoo.h"`, so I can avoid file name collisions in the future. How can this be done?

Comment: use include_directories to add paths for your *.h files

Comment: you probably should also specify `target_include_directories` with `libfoo`

Comment: I think `${LIBFOO_SRCS}` is supposed to be the sources. `"libfoo.h"` is not a source file and shouldn't be listed in `add_library`. Probably.

Comment: @nwp In CMake you usually do include both .cpp and .h files in the sources list.

Comment: Second @VTT comment, with the addition that you probably want to make sure to use the `PUBLIC` flag so that consumers also get the include directory.

Answer (score 0):

By having variable [CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR.html) set, you automatically include directory `libfoo/` (for search header files) when file `libfoo/CMakeLists.txt` is processed.

However, like with [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) command, this doesn't affect on the parent directory: `libfoo/` isn't included when `CMakeLists.txt` is processed. See, e.g., that question: [No such file or directory using cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164431/no-such-file-or-directory-using-cmake).

You may set variable [CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR_IN_INTERFACE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR_IN_INTERFACE.html), so `libfoo/` will be "**attached**" as include directory to any target created in `libfoo/CMakeLists.txt`. Thus, linking with such target (`libfoo` in your case) will propagate include directory.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# This will include current directory when building a target
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# This will *attach* current directory as include directory to the target
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR_IN_INTERFACE ON)
```

(Note, that it is sufficient to set the variables only in top-level `CMakeLists.txt`: all variables are automatically propagated to subdirectories.)

---

> I would prefer to have the required include directory for the libfoo.h library to be of the form #include "libfoo/libfoo.h"

So you need to have a file `<some-dir>/libfoo/libfoo.h` and include `<some-dir>`.